# VBA alternative to Excel SUMPRODUCT multiple criteria lookup

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I have a large spreadsheet with tens of thousands of rows. I want to look up values based on multiple criteria and get the associated values. Currently, I use the **SUMPRODUCT** function, but with that many rows, it takes many minutes to calculate.

Function:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((array 1 criteria) * (array2 criteria) * array values)
```

Example:

[image]

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B15:B23=”John”)*(C15:C23=”North”)*(E15:E23=1)*D15:D23)
```

Example from [here](https://www.myexcelonline.com/blog/advanced-sumproduct-function-sum-multiple-criteria/).

**Question:**
Is there a more efficient way to do this type of lookup with multiple criteria - maybe with VBA? I have tried using index match, but it only gives me the value of the first match and I am not sure it is better performance-wise.

Comment: Where would you like the result to be returned? Do you need a way to return each time when you select some criteria, or you need it to return for each row? In your case, your data not being sorted, where your `sumproduct` function does exist?

Comment: Have you tried using a pivot table? it would sum anything filtering by your criteria.

Comment: `SUMIFS` will probably work better, and is optimized to handle whole column references

Comment: In my scenario, there are two sheets with data from different sources. The main sheet aggregate values from the second sheet with the Sumproduct function for each row. A pivot table is therefore not possible unfortunately

Comment: How many `SUMPRODUCT` formulas do you have?

Comment: At least one for each row @chrisneilsen

Comment: So you mean 10,000's?

Comment: Do you mean that for each `John` you have a formula on the row, even if that `John` can be found 200 times?

Comment: Why do this with VBA? Why not use Power Query to combine data instead of lookups, and use Power Pivot to create relationships and FAST calculating measures. VBA is probably the worst possible approach for this scenario. Even Excel native formulas will be faster than VBA. You may need to rethink you approach.

Comment: I am open to other solutions @teylyn. One of the reasons I am not using Power Pivot is because it doesn't support many to many relationships natively

Comment: @FaneDuru not only for each "John" but for each row. The data is much more complex than my example described. I have a lot of data in a database, each month I get new data that needs to be validated before it is uploaded to the database. This requires a lot of checks (using standard Excel formulas and the sumproduct).

Comment: @2by: It is obvious that for each row. Meaning that for each John or Paul with their region you need the total sails amount. What I wanted to emphasize was why to calculate for each John, for instance, if all the results for such a name (in combination with the region) will be the same? Why not filtering as unique values and run it for each such case? Even if everything must be calculated, where the result to be returned? On column F:F of the row?

Comment: @FaneDuru and others: you are right that it is probably better to re-think my approach to this

Comment: *Let me add my two cents.* **I would bet my money that the biggest problem is that when you simply use this formula animations and screenrefreshing in excel add a lot of time** - there is a workaround for that though, you could still use the `SUMPRODUCT` formula however with a VBA macro and then disable all the things that slow Excel down such as: `ScreenUpdating`, `EnableEvents` etc. etc.

Comment: I will try that @DannyPapadopulos

Comment: @2by _I think the only real solution is to think of another way of doing it an avoid making lookups for each row altogether._ (OPs comment on FaneDurus' answer) Yes!  And had you bothered explaining what you actually want to achieve,  we might have been able to help you with that

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want to use Pivot try this.. As all the arguments are range, select desire range for entering the input.

```
Function VBSumProd(nameRng As Range, nameCrt As Range, regionRng As Range, regionCrt As Range, salesRng As Range, qtrRng As Range, qrtCrt As Range) As Double

Dim i As Long, tempSum As Double
tempSum = 0

For i = 1 To nameRng.Rows.Count
    If WorksheetFunction.And(UCase(nameRng(i)) = UCase(nameCrt), UCase(regionRng(i)) = UCase(regionCrt), qtrRng(i) = qrtCrt) Then
    tempSum = tempSum + salesRng(i)
    End If
Next

VBSumProd = tempSum
End Function
```

[image]

You tried code below which is slow compared to subtotal

```
Function VBSumProd(nameRng As Range, nameCrt As String, regionRng As Range, regionCrt As String, salesRng As Range, qtrRng As Range, qrtCrt)
Dim nameRngArr, regionRngArr, salesRngArr, qtrRngArr
Dim i As Long, tempSum As Double
tempSum = 0

ReDim nameRngArr(nameRng.Rows.Count)
ReDim regionRngArr(nameRng.Rows.Count)
ReDim salesRngArr(nameRng.Rows.Count)
ReDim qtrRngArr(nameRng.Rows.Count)

For i = 1 To nameRng.Rows.Count
    nameRngArr(i) = nameRng(i)
    regionRngArr(i) = regionRng(i)
    salesRngArr(i) = salesRng(i)
    qtrRngArr(i) = qtrRng(i)
Next

For i = 1 To nameRng.Rows.Count
    If WorksheetFunction.And(UCase(nameRngArr(i)) = UCase(nameCrt), UCase(regionRngArr(i)) = UCase(regionCrt), qtrRngArr(i) = qrtCrt) Then
    tempSum = tempSum + salesRngArr(i)
    End If
Next
VBSumProd = tempSum
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: I just tested this, and while it works it is much slower than using the built-in SUMPRODUCT formula. But thank you for your answer!

Comment: may be so because I used variant datatypes for calculation... try it with range object as per modified answer.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code. It is very fast, using array and working in memory. Please confirm that it works fast enough for your real case. It works in range "A2:D" & last row, and returns the result in column "E:E".

```
Sub testSumprodBis()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, arrI As Variant, arrF As Variant, lastR As Long
 Dim i As Long, j As Long, pCount As Long, d As Object

  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  lastR = sh.Range("A" & Cells.Rows.count).End(xlUp).row
  arrI = sh.Range("A2:D" & lastR).Value
  ReDim arrF(1 To UBound(arrI, 1), 1 To 1)
  Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

  For i = 1 To lastR - 1
    If Not d.Exists(UCase(arrI(i, 1) & arrI(i, 2) & arrI(i, 4))) Then
        For j = 1 To lastR - 1
            If UCase(arrI(i, 1)) = UCase(arrI(j, 1)) And arrI(i, 4) = arrI(j, 4) Then
                pCount = pCount + arrI(j, 3)
            End If
        Next j
        d(UCase(arrI(i, 1) & arrI(i, 2) & arrI(i, 4))) = pCount
        arrF(i, 1) = pCount: pCount = 0
    Else
        arrF(i, 1) = d(UCase(arrI(i, 1) & arrI(i, 2) & arrI(i, 4)))
    End If
  Next
  sh.Range("E2").Resize(UBound(arrF, 1), 1).Value = arrF
End Sub
```

Now, the code uses a dictionary where the already calculated cases are kept and only used for similar ones, instead of recalculating...

Edited: It works almost instant for my case, but this is happening because a only repeated the values taken form your above example. Please let me know how much it takes for your real file.

Comment: I just tested this, it works okay but is slower than Excel's SUMPRODUCT function. However, thank you for your answer. I think the only real solution is to think of another way of doing it an avoid making lookups for each row altogether.

Comment: How the data is updated in your file?  Isn't it possible to identify the updated  rows and run it only for those one, but calculating for all data range?  In such a case Sumproduct formulas will not be recalculated for all the range and it can work very fast...

Comment: When I will be at my office, I will try a different approach. In two, three hours... But, please, answer the previous question. If the data are updated by adding new rows I have in mind an idea...

Comment: Data is updated from a connection to CSV file - but don't waste more time on this I already took enough time. :-)

Comment: @2by: I am in my office and **I insist** to prepare a different approach, but keeping the most part of arrays iteration. It will not take me too  much. In principle, I intend to use a dictionary and keep in it the already calculated rows and only returning the calculate value, if the dictionary key is found. It will surely decrease the time. It is a lot of time consuming for iteration  in such a big array. In some minutes I will come with an updated code...

Comment: @2by: Updated. Please refresh the page and test the updated code and  give us a feedback regarding the code speed.