# Macro to Sumif Multiple Columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table in excel, i want to use macro to sum Amount base on 3 Criteria Column
this is my Table

[image]

so the Main Criteria to sum the amount are Column VendorName, Customer and Date.

When i Clicked the Button then If the VendorName, Customer and date are the same Value then on Column E (Subtotal) will Appear like this

(grouping based on Colour no need to give colour in Macro )

[image]

I have the macro like this

```
Dim i As Long
Dim Condition As Variant
Dim AVal As Variant
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim Hide, popup  As Long
Dim message  As String

Dim sht As Worksheet
'----------------------------
Dim dictionary As Object
Set dictionary = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
'---------------------------
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.StatusBar = False
'------------------
Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
Rows.EntireRow.Hidden = False
Columns("E:G").EntireColumn.Delete
Range("E:G").EntireColumn.Insert
Range("E1").Value = "SubTotal"

Set sht = ActiveSheet

LastRow = sht.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
'-------------------

For i = 2 To LastRow ' with last row count
     Condition = "A" & i & "=A" & i & "B" & i & "=B" & i & "C" & i & "=C" & i
    AVal = "A" & i & "B" & i & "C" & i
     Worksheets("VendorTotal").Range("E" & i).Formula = "=IF(" & Condition & ",SUMIF(A:C," & AVal & ",D:D))"

Next i
```

It Always Show N/A in Column E

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60365802/vba-alternative-to-excel-sumproduct-multiple-criteria-lookup/60366715?noredirect=1#comment106788168_60366715........ just a simpler suggestion

Comment: Your string building of `Condition` and `AVal` are wrong.  I'd suggest you build one of the formula by hand, compare that to what your code produces and adjust the code from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I Got enlightment from the answer  @BrownishMonster
using SUMIFS, i have made it to macro button

```
Dim i As Long
Dim Condition As Variant
Dim AVal As Variant
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim Hide, popup  As Long
Dim message  As String

Dim sht As Worksheet
'----------------------------
Dim dictionary As Object
Set dictionary = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
'---------------------------
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.StatusBar = False
'------------------
Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
Rows.EntireRow.Hidden = False
Columns("E:Z").EntireColumn.Delete
Range("E:Z").EntireColumn.Insert
Range("E1").Value = "Sum Total "

Set sht = ActiveSheet

LastRow = sht.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
'-------------------


For i = 2 To LastRow ' with last row count =SUMIFS(I:I,A:A,A8,B:B,B8,C:C,C8)

     AVal = "A" & i

     BVal = "B" & i

     CVal = "C" & i
     Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & i).Formula = "=SUMIFS(D:D,A:A," & AVal & ",B:B," & BVal & ",C:C," & CVal & ")"

Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

This does not use VBA so it doesn't *properly* answer your question, however you can use an Excel Formula.

You can use the [SumIfs](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/sumifs-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b) function as so:

```
=SumIfs(D:D,A:A,A2,B:B,B2)
```

You would copy this formula into each row, replacing `A2 and`B2` which the row number.

This formula would sum all of the values in `column D` on rows that match all of the following conditions:

1. The Text in `column A` for `RowX` matches the text in `column A` for `Row0`
2. The Text in `column B` for `RowX` matches the text in `column B` for `Row0`

Where `Row0` is the row the formula is entered on, and `RowX` is the row the formula is matching on.

```
  |   Vendor Name  |   Customer   |   Date   |   Amount   |   SubTotal
--+----------------+--------------+----------+------------+--------------
2 |PT ABC          | Asep         | 1/1/2020 | 1,000      | =SumIfs(D:D,A:A,A2,B:B,B2)
3 |PT ABC          | Asep         | 1/1/2020 | 2,000      | =SumIfs(D:D,A:A,A3,B:B,B3)
4 |PT ABC          | Asep         | 1/1/2020 | 3,000      | =SumIfs(D:D,A:A,A4,B:B,B4)
5 |PT ABC          | Reni         | 1/1/2020 | 1,000      | =SumIfs(D:D,A:A,A5,B:B,B5)
6 |PT XYZ          | Yono         | 1/1/2020 | 9,000      | =SumIfs(D:D,A:A,A6,B:B,B6)
7 |PT XYZ          | Yono         | 1/1/2020 | 1,000      | =SumIfs(D:D,A:A,A7,B:B,B7)
8 |PT XYZ          | Yono         | 1/1/2020 | 4,000      | =SumIfs(D:D,A:A,A8,B:B,B8)
9 |PT MNO          | Asep         | 1/1/2020 | 4,000      | =SumIfs(D:D,A:A,A9,B:B,B9)
10|PT MNO          | Asep         | 1/1/2020 | 2,000      | =SumIfs(D:D,A:A,A10,B:B,B10)
```

Comment: thanks dude, i have comvert your Formula to macro, and now its working